# Image overlaps the text block

Tags: html, css

**The code of my HTML document is as follows:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Wer ist Mats?</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .content {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      border: 2px white solid;
      background: white;
      max-width: 31.25em;
      margin: 12.5em;
      margin-top: 9.375em;
      margin-left: 25em;
    }
    .header {
      margin-bottom: 1.2em;
    }
    .text {
    }
    img {
      position: absolute;
      right: 25em;  
      margin-top: 9.375em;
      /* Schatten von http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/image-shadow.html ausprobiert */
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Wer ist Mats?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat ullam nulla officiis magnam quos repellat aliquam, nam eaque aspernatur modi possimus expedita dolores rem hic veniam quis veritatis repudiandae perspiciatis mollitia ipsam labore iusto! Corrupti qui asperiores facilis unde! Asperiores facere id ullam quod magnam animi laboriosam voluptates obcaecati modi possimus perspiciatis ad vero, esse fugit sint ab hic eligendi tenetur deleniti omnis ipsam nobis illum placeat! Sunt id quaerat impedit laborum ratione aperiam quo est quis eveniet dolor non, explicabo ab esse voluptate corporis minima omnis quae necessitatibus natus architecto distinctio. Asperiores officiis minima, quasi esse mollitia vel pariatur atque reiciendis laudantium cum, amet non delectus nemo suscipit error?<br><br> Laudantium incidunt voluptate sequi consequuntur cum magni sapiente maiores eos iure provident totam iste vel similique excepturi ipsam ipsum nobis unde deleniti nisi ullam, vero, quam quos. Labore tenetur consectetur commodi eius neque deleniti fugit quae ad iusto, eveniet aliquam quam itaque dignissimos, iure sit facilis voluptates laudantium quos consequuntur corporis vitae consequatur. Dolor tenetur placeat ad quasi earum nesciunt? Doloribus sint ex, repellat atque ipsa inventore voluptatem consequatur quaerat nemo suscipit magni harum fugiat ad perspiciatis alias provident. Facere reprehenderit quis praesentium delectus in architecto incidunt blanditiis accusantium molestiae culpa. Reprehenderit iste nulla eius placeat sunt quae laboriosam earum veritatis veniam molestias optio dignissimos nisi eaque, ea dolorem possimus debitis molestiae iusto beatae officiis? Officiis delectus, corporis vel facilis nisi eius quae recusandae quaerat officia deleniti sint adipisci, necessitatibus accusantium quis optio sequi. Explicabo harum vel alias perferendis quisquam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/05/20/30/girl-4455005_960_720.jpg" alt="Girl with a Horse">
</body>
</html>
```

[Here you can see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rwpq.jpg) of the actual Problem I have after opening the document in the browser.

My `<div class="text">` block goes under the picture, but in the fullscreen it works fine. Please help me, it's my first experience with HTML and CSS.

Comment: The problem is that you have `position: absolute` on the picture, which takes it out of the 'flow' of the arrangement of elements. You'll likely want to remove that, and instead replace it with `float: left` or `float: right` depending on exactly how you want it to sit in relation to the text. Without `position: absolute`, you'll be able to use `margin-left` and `margin-right` in order to align it better. However, given you're just starting out, you may want to look into a framework that will align elements for you responsively.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you very much. The Picture is disapearing now when I make the browser smaller but the text always stays at the same position. Why is that?

Comment: and it added a scrollbar?

Comment: `
 img {
      float: right;
      right: 25em;  
      margin-right:  200px;
      margin-top: 9.375em;
      /* Schatten von http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/image-shadow.html ausprobiert */
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
      -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nice to have your question, it looks like you simply need to handle the CSS Layout and still want it to be browser-width-friendly, or cross-device. I suggest learning Flexbox CSS Layout. Take your time learning the guides, [this may be helpful](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a quick start.

```css
article{display:flex}
.container{flex-direction:column}
p {width: 300px; flex-grow:3}
img {width:300px; flex-grow: 4}
```

```html
<article> 
<div class="container">
<h1>I'm title here</h1>
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat ullam nulla officiis magnam quos repellat aliquam, nam eaque aspernatur modi possimus expedita dolores rem hic veniam quis veritatis repudiandae perspiciatis mollitia ipsam labore iusto! Corrupti qui asperiores facilis unde! Asperiores facere id ullam quod magnam animi laboriosam voluptates obcaecati modi possimus perspiciatis ad vero, esse fugit sint ab hic eligendi tenetur deleniti omnis ipsam nobis illum placeat! Sunt id quaerat impedit laborum ratione aperiam quo est quis eveniet dolor non, explicabo ab esse voluptate corporis minima omnis quae necessitatibus natus architecto distinctio. Asperiores officiis minima, quasi esse mollitia vel pariatur atque reiciendis laudantium cum, amet non delectus nemo suscipit error?<br><br> Laudantium incidunt voluptate sequi consequuntur cum magni sapiente maiores eos iure provident totam iste vel similique excepturi ipsam ipsum nobis unde deleniti nisi ullam, vero, quam quos. Labore tenetur consectetur commodi eius neque deleniti fugit quae ad iusto, eveniet aliquam quam itaque dignissimos, iure sit facilis voluptates laudantium quos consequuntur corporis vitae consequatur. Dolor tenetur placeat ad quasi earum nesciunt? Doloribus sint ex, repellat atque ipsa inventore voluptatem consequatur quaerat nemo suscipit magni harum fugiat ad perspiciatis alias provident. Facere reprehenderit quis praesentium delectus in architecto incidunt blanditiis accusantium molestiae culpa. Reprehenderit iste nulla eius placeat sunt quae laboriosam earum veritatis veniam molestias optio dignissimos nisi eaque, ea dolorem possimus debitis molestiae iusto beatae officiis? Officiis delectus, corporis vel facilis nisi eius quae recusandae quaerat officia deleniti sint adipisci, necessitatibus accusantium quis optio sequi. Explicabo harum vel alias perferendis quisquam.</p>
</div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/05/20/30/girl-4455005_960_720.jpg" alt="Girl with a Horse">
</article>
```

You can change the `flex-grow` property of both text and image for them to be of desired ratio.

Comment: Hello you helped me out, but how can I add the H1 to the article. When I just add it in the article it gets next to the text?

Comment: @Bot-Mats, sorry for taking it long to answer - there is nothing comlicacted, simply wrap the text and title into the block which will align them vertically. The <article> is using flexbox properties, so for that container block you need to give a style of vertical alignment for its inner elements (children) which will be <h1> and <p> with their parent <div> with class .container{flex-direction:column}. Updated the code for you 